# Android - How to detect a single tap on a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

I have a View and I need to detect a single tap on a LinearLayout.
I don't care about movements, All I want to detect is a single tap.
Basically a touch detection just like the touch detection on buttons. How can I achieve this?

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // This gets called so many times on every movement
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: why dont you use a `onClickListener`?

Comment: This is a basic thing and I dont think you will find a single app that doesn't use a `View.onClickListener` See doc here -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, this would work aryaxt:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // myView tapped //
    }
});
```